# How do I raise my own Exception in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I copied and pasted these lines of code from a Python tutorial book. Why does this code not work when I try to run it in PyCharm?

```
def inputNumber ():
    x = input ('Pick a number: ')
    if x == 17:
      raise 'BadNumberError', '17 is a bad number'
    return x
inputNumber()
```

This is what I got when I run the code:

```
Pick a number: 17
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/arman/Desktop/Scribble/Hello.py", line 153, in <module>
    inputNumber()
  File "C:/Users/arman/Desktop/Scribble/Hello.py", line 151, in inputNumber
    raise 'BadNumberError', '17 is a bad number'
TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not str
```

Comment: That tutorial is *very much out of date* then. You want to pick a different tutorial. The last Python version that code would have worked without producing a deprecation warning was Python 2.2 (released 2001), and support was removed entirely from 2.6 (2008). A tutorial that uses concepts and syntax *this far behind the times* is going to have other problems too. Find something newer than ~15 years old.

Comment: Also, if you are just starting with Python, I recommend you start with Python 3, not 2. Python 2 has been end-of-lifed and 2.7 will only receive security fixes until 2020. Python 3 is where all the energy is going to.

Comment: I always wanted to learn newer versions but there is this machine vision course I took this semester that requires programming on Python 2.7...

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard exceptions:

```
raise ValueError('17 is a bad number')
```

Or you can define your own:

```
class BadNumberError(Exception):
    pass
```

And then use it:

```
raise BadNumberError('17 is a bad number')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be raising exceptions as raise as follows `BadNumberError('17 is a bad number')` if you have already defined `BadNumberError` class exception.

If you haven't, then

```
class BadNumberError(Exception):
    pass
```

And here is the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions) with information about raising exceptions

Comment: Provided there is such an exception class. There is not.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're completely right, i've updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I strongly suspect the OP will find other problems. Python 2.2 and older are ancient history by now..

Answer (score 0):

Just inherit from `Exception` class, then you can throw your own exceptions:

```
class BadNumberException(Exception):
    pass

raise BadNumberException('17 is a bad number')
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 4, in <module>
BadNumberException: 17 is a bad number
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define a [your own error](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions) you have to do:

```
class BadNumberError(Exception):
    pass
```

and then use it:

```
def inputNumber ():
    x = input ('Pick a number: ')
    if x == 17:
        raise BadNumberError('17 is a bad number')
    return x
inputNumber()
```